# Modular mailing

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

I am searching a way to send mail through PHP based on HTML template.
But the user that will send the email must be able to preview it and edit it if needed.

So I began to use [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to send the mail. It works very well.
I also used [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) to allow the user to preview the mail and edit it easily.

And I am a sort of blocked by this javascript library. There a lot of problem by sending html content to js (Parsing, carriage return, ...) The only way to get this working is to edit all my HTML templates... So it is definitly not a solution.

I also have to replace content of template.html by field stored in a database. It works too.

The main problem is passing a var containing all the HTML content to javascript ...

I have two ways to proceed:

- Finding library that helps make sending mail in a more modular way.
- Keep using my solution, but finding a way to send a var like `$test = "<html><h1>Title</h1><body>MyBody</body></html"` to javascript without triggering a billion errors.

### Bonus question

The HTML templates are not so heavy but I have +- 50 of them. Is it a good solution to store them in a database ?